# Want to read important double value at the end of line of istream C++

Tags: c++, io, ifstream

I'm trying to read in a large matrix calculated from a text file for a finite element code. The matrix is spatially dependent though and thus I need to be able to conveniently organize the data. The outside source that calculated the values for the matrix was kind enough to put the following lines at the top of the text file

```
No. activity levels :    3
No. pitch-angles    :   90
No. energies        :   11
No. L-shells        :   10
```

Which basically tell me the number of positions the matrix is known at. I want to be able to easily pick out these values because it will allow me to preallocate the size of the matrix, as well as know immediately how much I need to interpolate for values not given by this text file. I am trying to do that with the following code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){

  string diffusionTensorFileName = "BAS_drift_averaged_chorus_kp.txt";
  string sline;
  int alphaSize=0;
  ifstream diffusionTensorFile(diffusionTensorFileName.c_str());
  while(getline(diffusionTensorFile,sline)){

    if(strncmp(sline.c_str(),"No. pitch-angles    :   90",sline.size()-1)==0 && sline.size()-1 != 0){
      alphaSize = atoi(sline.c_str());
      printf("alphaSize %d \n", alphaSize);
      vector<double> alpha(alphaSize);
    }

  }

}
```

atoi of course doesn't work very well, and I can't seem to get strtod or any of those functions to work either. Any thoughts? I'm also open to this being the completely wrong way to do this and alternate suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: You have to tell `atoi` (or better yet, [`std::stol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)) where the number in the string starts. Remember that the function will skip leading whitespace. Making a [sub-string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) might be a good idea.

Comment: A couple of other things: You do know that [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) doesn't leave a newline in the string it reads into, and that [`std::string::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) returns the length of the string *without* any terminator. And that `std::string` have [comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to use the `scan_is` method of the `std::ctype` facet imbued in the streams locale. Its job is to search for first character that matches a given classification and return a pointer to it. We'll take the result of that call and use `std::stoi` (C++11) to parse it into an integer.

```
std::locale loc(diffusionTensorFile.getloc());
auto& f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(loc);

while (std::getline(diffusionTensorFile, sline))
{
    const char* begin = sline.front(),
                end   = sline.back() + 1;

    const char* result;
    if ((result = f.scan_is(f.digit, begin, end)) != end)
    {
        alphaSize = std::stoi(result);
        // do something with alphaSize
    }
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/a8qbBg)